# Get computed style in Jest Test

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, lwc-jest, dynamic-style

I have the following code.

Html template

```
<template>
    <tr class="table__row" aria-hidden={isHidden} data-test-class="table-row">
        <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

CSS

```
.table__row[aria-hidden="true"] {
    display: none;
}
```

JS Controller

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class Example extends LightningElement {
    isHidden = true;
}
```

Jest

```
import { createElement } from 'lwc';
import Example from 'c/example'

// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
const flushPromises = () => new Promise(resolve => setImmediate(resolve));

describe('starnger things', () => {
    it('expects to get display:none', async () => {
        const componentElement = createElement('c-example',{ is: Example });

        document.body.appendChild(componentElement);
        await flushPromises();

        const row = componentElement.shadowRoot.querySelector('[data-test-class="table-row"]');
        const styles = getComputedStyle(row);
        expect(row.ariaHidden).toBe('true')
        expect(row.classList.contains('table__row')).toBe(true)
        // next line fails with 'Received: "table-row"'
        expect(styles.display).toBe('none');
    });
});
```

I want to test the style change with Jest, but `getComputedStyle` for the table row returns `display: table-row`. Am I missing something? Or is it just impossible?

**Update**

I updated the code to make sure it's working and the issue is easily reproducible with the provided code.

I want to test specifically the `display: none` and not *how* it is achieved in order to segregate the behavior and the implementation.

Answer (score 3):

This kind of test is possible but there are several issues with your test code:

**1. Add the component to the DOM**

First of all, your test code doesn't add the component to the DOM. This is required for rendering the right properties in the dynamic template.

You need to add that after creating the the element:

```js
document.body.appendChild(componentElement);
```

**2. Use the right property/selector**

Then, you use an unsupported custom `test-data-class` attribute on the `tr` standard tag. This is not valid HTML and it's not needed as you can retrieve the element in your test by simply using the CSS class selector in `querySelector`:

```js
const row = componentElement.shadowRoot.querySelector('.table__row');
```

You could also retrieve the `tr` element if there's only one in your template:

```js
const row = componentElement.shadowRoot.querySelector('tr');
```

**3. Reconsider what you need to test**

Finally, while it will work, your test should not check if a static CSS rule is correctly applied using `getComputedStyle` because of separation of concern. In other words, you shouldn't be testing if the CSS engine does it work correctly, you should be testing if your component's JS/template dynamically renders as expected.

This means that you only need to check the value of `aria-hidden`. That's good enough for a proper test coverage:

```js
const componentElement = createElement('c-my-cmp',{ is: MyCmp });
document.body.appendChild(componentElement);
const row = componentElement.shadowRoot.querySelector('tr[aria-hidden="true"]');
expect(row).not.toBeNull();
```

Comment: Thanks @POZ, I knew you would answer the question. Thanks for pointing out the text code issue, I actually add the component to the DOM in the real test, but this code I quickly composed in the question directly... Let me fix the code. I actually check the aria-hidden attribute, but my concern is some future dev will accidentally or not change a tr class and will not find out the issue until he sees it

Comment: I updated the code, please take a look

Comment: Thanks for the updated code but I still think that you're not using Jest for the right use case. Jest uses JSDOM (a virtual headless browser) and there are limitations in terms of what it can do compared to a real browser (example: https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#pretending-to-be-a-visual-browser). You can't really test the content of your stylesheet this way. You likely need Selenium or another UI testing framework for that.